# Convert an RTSP/RTMP-Livestream with G.711 audio into RTMP/RTSP with aac-audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, rtsp, rtmp

im new at this forum and my english skills are not the best!

I have a website where i publish the videostreams of the cameras to show what happens inside during the nesting-time live! An guy with high IT-skills has build me a little Server for Restream it (Datarhei-Restreamer) But this guy has still no time and worse response-times...

To my Problem: The Restreamer dont support the "G.711" Audio-Codec from the cameras and the Livestream are still without audio at the website. So, i need to convert the Livestreams (RTSP and RTMP- in H.264) so that the audio changes to "aac" or something other supported. But i have no plan how to do this. I tried it with FFMPEG but i dont find the correct commands to get the my result. There is something with an Streaming-server to send the new created stream to - i dont get it into my head to do this (i need just a stream that are viewable with VLC player and then as input for my restreamer-server, jsut the same like ca

I want to change the source-stream into the correct codec (audio from G.711 to AAC, the rest like source) and then, put this "new" stream into my Restreamer-Server and it will work fine! (Tested with XSplitbroadcaster, but dont runs on Raspberry, only 1 instance runable but 2 livestreams needs to be encoded at same time) And this programm has annoying bugs (endless and not removeable error-messages, but running stream)

I have a new second raspberry that are planned as "live-encoder" for the restreamer-raspberry were the "new" streams are are going in (rtmp/rtsp-input on a graphical ui) I try it still with FFMPEG but still no result...

Sorry about this long text with all the language-issues but im really frustrated with it because i have purchased 2 new cameras with total 450 euros just to get the livestream with sound now :(

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I found the best solution here and it works (https://github.com/datarhei/restreamer/issues/11). Inside the long discussion, use the solution written by *svenerbeck* on *4 Apr 2016*. The essential part is written below.

1. Create a new `live.json` in `/mnt/live.json` with the upcoming modification:

   `"ffmpeg": {
       "options": {
           "native_h264": [
               "-vcodec copy",
               "-acodec aac",
               "-f flv"
           ],
          .....`
2. Exec the container with

   `docker run ... -v /mnt/live.json:/restreamer/conf/live.json ....`